# Adding obj files to github

Tags: git, github

I am working with VS2013 and my team has a lot of obj files we need to share and would like to store them in a github repo but whenever we add the files and their respective class files, the class show up just fine but the obj do not dispite being in the repo directory.

Anyone know how to force the file in?

Comment: Have you made sure that your obj files are not excluded in `.gitignore`?

Comment: i searched that file so many times... That was the problem. I am going to pretend i didn't ask this

Comment: *headdesk twice to fill char limit*